# Need an Explanation about decoder

Tags: boolean-logic, decoder

I've gone through the decoder truth table and able to understand that. but i want to know why the corresponding output values related to input values get 1.

Example if we consider 2 to 4 Decoder when inputs are 1 1 then the output will be 1 0 0 0 the 4th place will get 1.

I need a reason why this is happening ?

Comment: Because that's how it was built? A look at a circuit diagram will tell you why this is happening at the technical level--I'm not sure I understand the question. (Noting that a decoder could be built to decode two inputs however we wanted to decode them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line decoder is designed to turn **code**(encoded boolean values) into **mutually-exclusive signals** (only one of the outputs can be 1) as you can see from the decoder truth table. A schema and circuitry for the decoder is implemented using this truth table because that is the **behavior** we are trying to create in our circuitry.